# Expectation of difference between amount of white and black cells on the infinite chessboard that the king will visit

Tags: probability-theory, expected-value, chessboard

The king is being randomly moved on the infinite chessboard. What is the expectation of modulus of difference between amount of white and black cells, which the king will visit by n steps. Each cell is counted as many times as king visits it.

Seemingly it is not that hard considering that the king has 8 cells to go (4 white, 4 black) and one can think that probabilities of coming to white and black cells are the same and expectation should equals to 0. But I feel that here is a catch and it's way more complex task

Comment: Do we count the king's starting square?

Comment: I was thinking about it and I suppose we shouldn't count it

Comment: You are asked to find the expectation of $|W-B|$ which is more difficult than finding the expectation of $W-B$ (which is obviously $0$ as you stated).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If $W$ denotes the number of visits to white cells then $W$ has binomial distribution with parameters $n$ and $p=\frac{1}{2}$.

To be found is: $$\mathbb{E}\left|W-\left(n-W\right)\right|=\mathbb{E}\left|2W-n\right|=2^{-n}\sum_{w=0}^{n}\left|2w-n\right|\binom{n}{w}$$

Can you do that yourself?

Comment: Thank you, now it's clear! I think I can manage it

Comment: You are very welcome.